# Displaying custom chevron for select using select::before

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the chevron icon to a SVG and to make it adjust to dark theme.
For that, I'm trying to set the chevron as background image to a separate element (::before) and apply the invert filter just to that.

```js
function toggle() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
}
```

```css
:root {
 --fill-color-background: #F3F3F3;
 --fill-color-text-primary: #000000E4;
 --fill-color-control-default: #FFFFFFB2;
 --fill-color-control-border: #0000000F;
}

.dark-theme {
  --fill-color-background: #202020;
  --fill-color-text-primary: #FFFFFF;
  --fill-color-control-default: #FFFFFF0F;
  --fill-color-control-border: #FFFFFF12;
}

body {
  background: var(--fill-color-background);
}

select, button {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 6rem;
  min-height: 0.0625rem;
  padding: 0.3125rem 0.75rem 0.4375rem 0.75rem;
  color: var(--fill-color-text-primary);
  background: var(--fill-color-control-default);
  border: 1px var(--fill-color-control-border) solid;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  overflow: hidden; /* Don't show excess chars */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Force single line */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: relative;

  &.static {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="8" height="6" viewBox="0 0 8 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M-0.00195312 1.5C-0.00195312 1.42969 0.0117188 1.36523 0.0390625 1.30664C0.0664062 1.24414 0.101562 1.19141 0.144531 1.14844C0.191406 1.10156 0.244141 1.06445 0.302734 1.03711C0.365234 1.00977 0.431641 0.996094 0.501953 0.996094C0.576172 0.996094 0.640625 1.00977 0.695312 1.03711C0.75 1.06055 0.802734 1.09766 0.853516 1.14844L4 4.29492L7.14648 1.14844C7.24805 1.04688 7.36523 0.996094 7.49805 0.996094C7.56836 0.996094 7.63281 1.00977 7.69141 1.03711C7.75391 1.06445 7.80664 1.10156 7.84961 1.14844C7.89648 1.19141 7.93359 1.24414 7.96094 1.30664C7.98828 1.36523 8.00195 1.42969 8.00195 1.5C8.00195 1.63672 7.95312 1.75391 7.85547 1.85156L4.35156 5.35547C4.25391 5.45312 4.13672 5.50195 4 5.50195C3.86328 5.50195 3.74609 5.45312 3.64844 5.35547L0.144531 1.85156C0.046875 1.75391 -0.00195312 1.63672 -0.00195312 1.5Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.6063"/></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 0.75rem center;
    background-size: 8px 6px;
  }
}

select:not(.static)::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="8" height="6" viewBox="0 0 8 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M-0.00195312 1.5C-0.00195312 1.42969 0.0117188 1.36523 0.0390625 1.30664C0.0664062 1.24414 0.101562 1.19141 0.144531 1.14844C0.191406 1.10156 0.244141 1.06445 0.302734 1.03711C0.365234 1.00977 0.431641 0.996094 0.501953 0.996094C0.576172 0.996094 0.640625 1.00977 0.695312 1.03711C0.75 1.06055 0.802734 1.09766 0.853516 1.14844L4 4.29492L7.14648 1.14844C7.24805 1.04688 7.36523 0.996094 7.49805 0.996094C7.56836 0.996094 7.63281 1.00977 7.69141 1.03711C7.75391 1.06445 7.80664 1.10156 7.84961 1.14844C7.89648 1.19141 7.93359 1.24414 7.96094 1.30664C7.98828 1.36523 8.00195 1.42969 8.00195 1.5C8.00195 1.63672 7.95312 1.75391 7.85547 1.85156L4.35156 5.35547C4.25391 5.45312 4.13672 5.50195 4 5.50195C3.86328 5.50195 3.74609 5.45312 3.64844 5.35547L0.144531 1.85156C0.046875 1.75391 -0.00195312 1.63672 -0.00195312 1.5Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.6063"/></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0.75rem center;
  background-size: 8px 6px;
}

.dark-theme select::before {
  filter: invert(); /* Adjusts the SVG color */
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body class="dark-theme">
    <div>
      <select tabindex="1">
        <option>First</option>
      </select>

      <select class="static" tabindex="1">
        <option>Second</option>
      </select>

      <button type="button" onclick="toggle()">
        Toggle Theme
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the second select (with a static chevron) is working as intended.
So looks like there's somethign wrong with the `select::before` rule.
Ignore the `:not(.static)` modifier as in my tests here I'm not using that.

I could simply have two SVG's of different color, but I'd rather try to use filter() first.

---

### Updated

I'm using a font icon instead and it works with `button` but not for `select` elements:

[image: Example]

```
select, button {
  position: relative;
}

select::before, button::before {
  content: '\e006';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: icons !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: So a side concern would be the chevrons don't display on firefox, in general though if you're planning on having multiple custom icons you'll want to easily keep theme compliant I'd strongly recommend just loading your SVG's into a Glyph Font like how [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) does it. You can make your own font with [Ico Moon](https://icomoon.io/) so you just var the `color` and can use as CSS class or unicode like it's text and just makes life easier in general.

Comment: Ah. bummer :/ So I would use the like this? :before { content: '^' font-family: custom, color: var(--color) } ?

Comment: Yea almost exactly, if you made it into a glyph font you'd just use it as unicode for that scenario `content: '\de3v'; font-family: 'Your_Custom_Font'; color: var(--color-var)` or to an element `<i class="your-prefix-<icon name>"></i>` etc. When you generate with the site I linked it generates a demo file with the class names and unicode values and examples etc. Pretty handy.

Comment: Yes, but there's an issue with the css rule, as anything that I put there in the content is not appearing. If I apply the same rule to buttons, it appear normally. See updated question above. :)

Comment: Unrelated, you might like to know you can use `document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme', isDark);` or even just `document.body.classList.toggle('dark-theme');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question has kind of gone from theme strategy to element quirks, the `select` element explicitly is lacking in customization friendliness yet. I just do something like this when I have to use the `select` element specifically.

Notice we just give the illusion with a wrapper element instead of fighting against sanity :D

Used FontAwesome for the example but same applies to your instance.

```css
.the-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: #ddd 2px solid;
}

.the-container:after {
  content: '\2b';
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 6 Free';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.the-container:hover {
  color: green;
  border-color: green;
}

.the-container select {
  -moz-appearance:none; 
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  appearance: none;
  /*outline: none;*/
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="the-container">
  <select>
    <option>ONE</option>
    <option>TWO</option>
    <option>THREE</option>
  </select>
</div>
```